# COnstructor Injection with roboguice enters inifinite loop

Tags: java, android, roboguice

HI I come from a background C#/.NET and have learned to work with a bit of Android.Now I am wana start to build a small app for fun and I tought to learn an IoC framework.After a bit of googeling I found roboguice.But I can not figure out how to integrate it.On .

NET I have worked with Ninject and Unity , and am looking to create a similar form of constructor injection that I got from those frameworks.

Here is what I have so far and what I think I have figured out:

This class represent the app bootstrapper and here is where I will register my dependency config class:

```
public class IOCApplication extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(this, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this), new IOCModule());
}
```

}

This is the Dependency config class:

```
 public class IOCModule implements Module{

        @Override
        public void configure(com.google.inject.Binder binder) {
            binder.bind(ITest.class).to(Test.class);
        }
    }
```

In my AndroidManifest I have added this:

```
<application ... android:name="com.example.project2.IOCApplication">
```

This part I do not realy understad why I had to add but I am thinking it's something to tell Android that IOCApplication should be isntantiated first.

This is the clas my MainActivily class and I have added a constructor for it:

```
public ITest test;
public MainActivity(ITest test){
    this.test = test;
}
```

When I try to runthis on my android device it kind of looks like the app is entering an infinite loop and I do not think ITest get's instantiated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to know with Android is that **you do not instantiate your own activities**, it is the system which does.

Because of this, you cannot use constructor injection with activities.
However, you can use attribute injection, which is cleaner IMO.

Extending the `RoboActivity` class is the easiest way to use injection with `Activity`.
RoboGuice provides similar classes for other Android components (`RoboFragment`, `RoboService`, etc.)

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @Inject
    ITest test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // You can now use your test instance
    }

}
```

All attribute with the `@Inject` will be instantiated after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is called.

---

With **POJO** (Plain Old Java Object), you have more options:

*Attribute injection*

```
public class Test {
    @Inject
    private Service1 service1;
    @Inject
    private Service2 service2;

    public Test() {
    }
}
```

*Constructor injection*

```
public class Test {

    private Service1 service1;
    private Service2 service2;

    @Inject
    public Test(Service1 service1, Service2 service2) {
        this.service1 = service1;
        this.service2 = service2;
    }
}
```

Note that your constructor must have the `@Inject` annotation if it has arguments.

---

You need this line `<application ... android:name="com.example.project2.IOCApplication">` to tell the system that you are using an extended `Application` class. Without it, Android will use the base class.

I encourage you to read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) for more information.